# Spring boot controller handle Java future

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, kafka-producer-api

I have a normal spring boot application with controller and service like following:

```
@RestController
class EventController(private val service: Service) {

  @GetMapping(value = ["xxx"], provides = [APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  fun get() {
    // call service?? is that right way?
    service.get()
  }
}

class Service {
  fun get(): Future<String> {
    xxx
  }
}
```

However, because some of third party API I used, let's say Kafka Producer API, and the service has to return a java future (`java.util.concurrent.Future`) and how should I handle this future result in my controller?

Comment: What do you want to do with the result of the `Future`? If you just need to pass the result of the `Future` then simply return the `Future`.

Comment: why not use **service.get().get()** to get the result

Comment: @clevertension yes, that's what I am currently doing but after read some articles and all recommend not calling `get()` method on a future in production code.

Comment: A spring controller can be async in nature, so just return it and spring will do the handling of the result.